# Unable to install software due to low space

Tags: disk-usage

I have 1TB hard disk storage.
[image]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/1ba7db5c-e921-4f4d-b6a5-022e51ada414/softwares$ du -hs /home/ubuntu 
447M     /home/ubuntu 
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/1ba7db5c-e921-4f4d-b6a5-022e51ada414/softwares$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use%  Mounted on
tmpfs           784M  2.0M  782M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       7.3G  4.4G  2.9G  61% /cdrom
/cow            3.9G  803M  3.1G  21% /
tmpfs           3.9G   74M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G  4.5M  3.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           784M  164K  784M   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sda4       450G   82M  427G   1% /medta/ubuntu/1ba7db5c-e921-4f4d-b6a5-022e51ada414
/dev/sda5       227G   11G  204G   5% /medta/ubuntu/f20eed97-5a39-4486-bdae-2645cd227df2
/dev/sda2       238G  8.1G  218G   4% /medta/ubuntu/9e20aede-5b3b-48bc-9e15-b37335c80156
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/1ba7db5c-e921-4f4d-b6a5-022e51ada414/softwares$
```

Whereas, while installing any software like docker,intelliJ; it will complain that the low space error.

I am totally new to ubuntu; how to resolve this?

Comment: Please add terminal output as copied text instead of a picture. You certainly have available space in the system partition, so that cannot be the problem. Use "edit" to clarify your question, in particularly with respect to what you tried and what happened. If you say "it complained", then it is difficult to imagine what you mean by "it".

Comment: You system disk is only 3.9 GB (`/cow`, mounted on `/` - I wonder if this is a `brtfs` partition?) - this is extremely small. What decision led you to have such a small root partition?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install things on the install-media.  Did you create it with "persistence"?  Do you understand the difference between a full install and the install-media?

Comment: Was this data taken while a live filesystem was running?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me! I just read your question and I will try my best to help you solve it.

I think you do not need to mount multiple differ version `Ubuntu` medias on your VM `Ubuntu`.

I just choose one version `Ubuntu` to mount on `/media/.` for an optional `Ubuntu`.

I suggest you unmount one of them medias, or even two of them.

Just using free `/dev/sda2` for an example. Free partiton `/dev/sda2`, then expand partition `/cow`, then your root `/` will have large space size `241.9 GB`. Also, you can install software later.

Solution:

0.please backup your target `Ubuntu` which mount at partition `/dev/sda2`;

1.unmount partition `/dev/sda2`'s Ubuntu version, then your VM will free `238GB`;

2.just use `cfisk` or `fdisk` or `parted` to remove the partition `/dev/sda2`

3.resize or move partition `/cow` to let that cover the space of the formal partition `/dev/sda2`, only in this way, your partition `/cow` has `241.9GB`;

4.set all the file types of partition `/cow` into target `ext4` via `sudo resize2fs /cow`;

5.Restart or reboot your virtual machine: `sudo reboot`.

Have fun!!!:)

OVER!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).